# JAXB how to nest several objects?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've been trying to search how to do this but I haven't found an answer to my exact requirements:

Let's say we had this 3 classes:

```
public class Main {
    public ArrayList<MyFirstClass> myFirstClass;
}

class MyFirstClass {
    public int num;
    public MySecondClass mySecondClass;
}

class MySecondClass {
    public String otherStr;
    public MyThirdClass myThirdClass;
}

class MyThirdClass {
    public int otherNum;
}
```

I wanto to be able to read these XML with the unmarshaller:

```
<Main>
    <MyFirstClasses>
        <MyFirstClass>
            <num>1</num>
            <MySecondClass>
                <str>Hello</str>
                <MyThirdClass>
                    <otherNum>2</otherNum>
                </MyThirdClass>
            </MySecondClass>
        </MyFirstClass>
    <MyFirstClasses>
</Main>
```

Where I'm basically able to set the variables that are objects (MySecond/Third Class).

I know I can use `@XMLRootElement` and then `@XmlElementWrapper(name="aName")` and `@XmlElement(name="aName")` to do the

```
<Main>
    <MyFirstClasses>
        <MyFirstClass>
            <num>1</num>
        </MyFirstClass>
    <MyFirstClasses>
</Main>
```

But how can I then nest the MySecondClass inside MyFirstClass so I can set it's values, because otherwise the FirstClassObject will have a MySecondClass which has null values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your xml does not match your POJOs. You can use annotations to fix this(renaming fields would also work). Try this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Main")
public class Main {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "MyFirstClasses")
    @XmlElement(name = "MyFirstClass")
    private List<MyFirstClass> myFirstClass;
}
```

Then FirstClass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyFirstClass {
    private int num;
    @XmlElement(name = "MySecondClass")
    private MySecondClass mySecondClass;
}
```

And MySecondClass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MySecondClass {
    private String str;

    @XmlElement(name = "MyThirdClass")
    private MyThirdClass myThirdClass;
}
```

Finally MyThirdClass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyThirdClass {
    public int otherNum;
}
```